# Developing for ASP.NET-MVC without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Instead of writing my ASP.NET C# applications in Visual Studio, I used my favorite text editor UltraEdit32.

Is there any way I can implement MVC without the use of VS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing VS specific with the MVC framework - it is just a bunch of DLLs that you can use. The wizards in VS just build you a quick-start framework.

ASP.NET MVC is "bin-deployable" - there is nothing too clever to set up on the server either - just point the wildcard ISAPI filter to ASP.NET

Comment: ok, so the answer is "Yes, you can build an ASPNET MVC app without Visual Studio."  For details on *how* :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451138/

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have the correct assemblies and a C# compiler you in theory can use whatever you want to edit the code and then just run the compiler by hand or using a build script. That being said it is a real pain doing .NET development without Visual Studio/SharpEdit/Monodevelop in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you didn't want to actually *edit* in VS, you could create the project there and edit the files in another editor.

Answer (score 1):

For small to mid size mvc project [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) is not bad at all. Also for simple changes to the projects I often use SublimeText.