# ASP.net MVC 2 and MonoDevelop 2.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, mono, monodevelop

Is it possible to utilize MVC 2 from MonoDevelop 2.2 (using Mono 2.4)? If so - is it as simple as grabbing a reference to the new System.Web.Mvc or is there something else to consider?

I realize that any templating support in MonoDevelop may not be 100% there since it was built to utilize MVC v1 (at least as of MonoDevelop 2.2).

If anyone can add any other tips or tricks that would help as well.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  I'm needing to do the same thing, and would rather not have to install a windows VM if I can.

Comment: Like the answer below - you can technically do it but there is zero support in the IDE. Your best bet would be to utilize a Windows VM that has support for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible as ASP.NET MVC is not Visual Studio specific. You can check the replies in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451138/) SOF question for more details.